# Acrobat Reader can't open .pdf generate by DomPDF

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

i'm using DomPDF to generate a pdf file . I'm also embedded a chinese font using load_font but i don't know why acrobat reader can't open it . tried document reader or foxit reader,chrome view it open normally . 
the error:

```
there was an error processing a page. there was a problem reading this document (135)
```

My html:

```
<span style="color: #000;font-family:Arial,chinese,sans-serif;"> @content@</span>
```

dompdf_font_family_cache:

```
'chinese' => 
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'chinese',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'chinese',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'chinese',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'chinese',
  ),
```

php code:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($voucherpdf);
$dompdf->set_paper(DOMPDF_DEFAULT_PAPER_SIZE, "landscape");
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

if i remove chinese and generate again then the acrobat reader can open normally

So anyone can give me a solution , tried many way found it but none of worked.

Comment: Post a link to one of the failing PDFs so we can see if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: here the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx9yjLWu3eOwMml2a2NEX3l2RG8

Comment: Better if you can provide a direct link to the PDF, it's possible that google or some other program cleaned up any issues in the PDF. That being said, some structural issues have been fixed in in the most recent release of dompdf. You might try upgrading to 0.7.0.